# How to modify this PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

This is my first time asking on this website and I guess this is a very basic problem but I am lost and I don't know what to do.

This is the PowerShell script:

```
$List1 = (Get-Content .\one.csv)
$List2 = (Get-Content .\two.csv)

$FullList = $List1 + $List2 | select -uniq

$report = @()

foreach ($item in $FullList) {

    If ($List1.Contains($item)) {
        $ExistsInList1 = $true
    }
    else {
        $ExistsInList1 = $false
    }
    
    If ($List2.Contains($item)) {
        $ExistsInList2 = $true
    }
    else {
        $ExistsInList2 = $false
    }
    
    $report += New-Object psobject -Property @{Item=$item;List1=$ExistsInList1;List2=$ExistsInList2}

}

$report | select Item, List1, List2 | Export-Csv -Path Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This script gets the contents of the first file and the second file then finds the difference. In the output file, I need it to show just the lines with differences (false-true/true-false) and ignore those that are still the same (true-true). I would really appreciate if anyone could give me a hand on this. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1).  It's designed for just this sort of thing.

Comment: Agree with BoxDog, `Compare-Object` should get what you want you want.

Comment: [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1) was also my first thought.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I never knew it was that simple. Thanks :)